# How to execute Sparql delete query using jena?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, virtuoso

I'm trying to execute a delete query using Jena, but I'm getting an error while executing it. I've tried two ways, but in both cases, I'm getting the same error. I'm using jena 2.7.3 and database virtuoso 6.01.3.

Code 1:

```java
String queryString; // deleteQuery.
Model m = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(file, connectionURL, username, password); 
UpdateAction.parseExecute(queryString, m);
```

Code 2:

```java
String queryString; // deleteQuery
Model m = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(file, connectionURL, username, password); 
GraphStore gs = GraphStoreFactory.create();
gs.setDefaultGraph(m.getGraph());            
UpdateRequest ur = UpdateFactory.create(queryString);            
UpdateAction.execute(ur.getOperations().get(0),gs);
```

Error:

> java.lang.InstantiationError: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.binding.BindingMap
>       at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryEngine$VQueryIterator.extractRow(Unknown Source)
>       at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryEngine$VQueryIterator.moveForward(Unknown Source)
>       at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryEngine$VQueryIterator.hasNextBinding(Unknown Source)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:108)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:40)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:108)
>       at org.openjena.atlas.data.AbstractDataBag.addAll(AbstractDataBag.java:74)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateEngineWorker.visit(UpdateEngineWorker.java:348)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.request.UpdateModify.visit(UpdateModify.java:97)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateEngineMain.execute(UpdateEngineMain.java:40)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessorBase.execute(UpdateProcessorBase.java:56)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.execute$(UpdateAction.java:330)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.execute(UpdateAction.java:323)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.execute(UpdateAction.java:283)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.execute(UpdateAction.java:237)
>       at com.tcs.ignite.plc.DAOs.ConceptDAO.deleteConceptByURI(ConceptDAO.java:75)
>       at com.tcs.ignite.plc.utilities.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.java:35)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: [see this](http://www.mail-archive.com/owlim-discussion@ontotext.com/msg01415.html)

Comment: The comment reference is to OWLIM, not Virtuoso.

Answer (score 3):

The comment reference is to OWLIM, not Virtuoso.  The cause is the same though - bad mix of versions.  You need to find out which version of Jena to use with database virtuoso 6.01.3.

An alternative is to run the Virtuoso database as a server and connect to it over the SPARQL protocol.  Then the version of Jena (the SPARQL protocol client) is not tied to the version sync'ed to Virtuoso.

Comment: Only downside of the second suggestion is that Virtuoso does not yet properly support all of SPARQL 1.1 Update so depending on what commands you send they may fail on the Virtuoso side

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code for send your query directly to Virtuoso server without using any Jena SPARQL parsers/executors.

```java
String queryString; // deleteQuery
Model m = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(file, connectionURL, username, password); 
VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, m);
vur.exec();
```